# Php : variable into SQL QUERY (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm calling a table from mySQL database using PDO as you can see :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE chapitre=\'hello\' ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Now, I want to do the same thing but instead of 'hello' I would like to use a variable set before like that :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE chapitre=\'echo $cat\' ORDER BY id DESC');
```

It doesn't work. I may have a problem with "echo $cat". Somebody knows ? Thanks.

Comment: in sql queries you do not echo variables. You use them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use binded variables, I don`t know where the variable is coming from but to be safe:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE chapitre=:cat ORDER BY id DESC');
$reponse->bindParam(':cat', $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR); //assuming it is a string
$reponse->execute();
$result = $reponse->fetchAll(); //make the select
print_r($result);  //debug
```

Comment: You just beat me to the punch haha. Nice answer :)

Comment: Hehe, happens to me allot too :P

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to echo the variable when passing it as argument. Wrap the whole string in [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and place the variable. 
Double quotes strings are parsed by PHP to place the variable values in string.

Use it in this way

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE chapitre= '$cat' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

your query can be:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE 
chapitre=\''.$cat.'\' ORDER BY id DESC');
```

you should understand the difference between "" and '', also you can " in 2 single quota without any problem and vice versa. if you want write " in 2 double quota you should use \ also the same when you write ' in 2 single quota.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do a query like that is this:

```
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$response = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE chapitre= :cat ORDER BY id DESC");
$response->bindParam(':cat', $cat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$response->execute();
```

I like this the best as it's clean and easy to understand.